# How can I operate matlab-like concatenate to get a new array

Tags: python

in Matlab, array[] = [1 2 3 4 5 6], we can have operation like :

```
array= [zeros(1,3) tones(3:6) zeros(1,1) tones(1:2) zeros(1,5)];
array[] = [0 0 0 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0]
```

is there any similiar way in python to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the same result using:

- '`*`' unpacking operator
- slicing or range
- defining list of n elements

code:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print ([*[0]*3 , *arr[2:6], *[0]*1, *arr[0:2], *[0]*5])

print ([*[0]*3 , *range(3,7), *[0]*1, *range(1,3), *[0]*5])
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [0]*3 + list(range(3, 7)) + [0] + list(range(1,3)) + [0]*5

print(x) # [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0 for i in range(3)] + [i for i in range(3,7)]
   +[0 for i in range(1)] + [i for i in range(1,3)]
   +[0 for i in range(5)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact array like version for Python may be:

```
>>> array = np.hstack((np.zeros(3),np.arange(3,7),np.zeros(1),np.arange(1,3),np.zeros(5)))

>>> array
array([0., 0., 0., 3., 4., 5., 6., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```